# Didn't find class "com.google.example.games.bc.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList

Tags: android, eclipse, multiplayer, google-play-games

I wanted to see an example of a multiplayer game and

I downloaded android game example ([here](https://github.com/playgameservices/android-basic-samples)).

I followed the guide "**If you're using Eclipse..**."

but It doesn't work with Eclipse.

This is the problem:

```
01-13 06:44:00.810: E/AndroidRuntime(970): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.google.example.games.bc.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.google.example.games.bc-2.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.google.example.games.bc-2, /system/lib]]
```

Can you help me?

Thank you.

Comment: Did you change the package name to bc-2?  I know changing the package name is in the instructions, but can you try changing it back to bc and seeing if it works like that?

Comment: @hatboysam not works.
Add more log details
>01-16 03:08:16.110: I/ActivityManager(388): Start proc com.google.example.games.bc for activity com.google.example.games.bc/.MainActivity: pid=1160 uid=10053 gids={50053}
01-16 03:08:16.670: I/dalvikvm(1160): Failed resolving Lcom/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity; interface 456 'Lcom/google/android/gms/common/api/GoogleApiClient$ConnectionCallbacks;'
01-16 03:08:16.670: W/dalvikvm(1160): Link of class 'Lcom/google/example/games/bc/MainActivity;' failed
01-16 03:08:16.680: D/AndroidRuntime(1160): Shutting down VM